# adding action to alertView Button

Tags: ipad, uibutton, uialertview

I everybody,

I have 3 Buttons each one calls an AlertView with "Cancel" and "OK" and each "OK" Button goes to an different view.

for now I solved this with this

```
- (UIButton *)1_BTN
{ 
 if (1_BTN == nil)
 {
  UIImage *buttonBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_btn.png"];
  UIImage *buttonBackgroundPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_btn.png"];

  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(655, 985, 107, 30);

  1_BTN = [_IPadAppDelegate buttonWithTitle:@""
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(1_BTN:)
                                      frame:frame
                                      image:buttonBackground
                               imagePressed:buttonBackgroundPressed];
 [1_BTN setTag:1];
}
return 1_BTN;
}
......

- (void)1_BTN:(NSInteger *)sender
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"some fancy text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];

[alert setTag:[sender valueForKey:@"tag"]];
[alert show];
[alert release]; 
}

.......

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex { 

if (buttonIndex == 1) {
if ([[alertView tag] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
something should happen.....
}
```

for all three Buttons and it works fine but for

```
[alert setTag:[sender valueForKey:@"tag"]];
```

and

```
 if ([[alertView tag] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
```

i get this warning "Invalid receiver Type "NSInteger""

why is that so and how can I solve this better?

Comment: Please layout better your code. Please use the code markup for your actual code, this makes it much better to analyze your problem.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you're doing this entirely wrong. Implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate`, specifically `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` and check which button index (from `0 .. n` where `n` is the last button). Act accordingly based on your known fixed indices.

Secondly, `NSInteger` is a scalar non-object type, and cannot receive messages. You would want an equality comparison instead, i.e., `alertview.tag == 1`. But as I said previously, don't do it that way.

Comment: I tried this in the first place but cause then the  "OK" button gehts always the same action that is why i tried the tags and since it worked that way........

only the warnings still bothers me.

Comment: Just because something works one way, doesn't mean you should do it that way. You should do it the delegate way, and based on the index of the button that was tapped, take appropriate action. This is the way you SHOULD do it.

Answer (score 1):

The UIView property "tag" isn't an object, it is just a simple NSInteger. It's almost the same as "int" you probably know from C/C++. I corrected a few line in your code. Now it should work.

Another thing: The allocation of the UIButton seems a bit strange to me. Maybe you should check your memory management.

```
- (UIButton *)1_BTN
    { 
         if (1_BTN == nil) { 
             UIImage *buttonBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_btn.png"]; 
             UIImage *buttonBackgroundPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_btn.png"];

             CGRect frame = CGRectMake(655, 985, 107, 30);

             1_BTN = [_IPadAppDelegate buttonWithTitle:@"" target:self selector:@selector(1_BTNAction:) frame:frame image:buttonBackground imagePressed:buttonBackgroundPressed]; 
            [1_BTN setTag:1]; 
         } 
         return 1_BTN; 
    }




    - (void)1_BTNAction:(UIButton *)sender {
        NSInteger tagNumber = [sender tag];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"sone fancy text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];

        [alert setTag:tagNumber]; 
        [alert show]; 
        [alert release]; 
    }



    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            if ([alertView tag] == 1) {
                //something should happen
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks burki that makes it a bit better to read but now i get the same warnung or NSInteger tagNumber = [sender tag];

Comment: Well, can you explain the error? Is it just a syntax error or does the app terminate when you press the button?